# Display image on screen while charging on Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am writing an Android application that should display the specific image (`Bitmap`) while the user is charging his phone.

The life-cycle:

1. User installs my application.
2. User **does not have to run my application**.
3. When user connects the charger (usb to PC or just an charger), my application **automatically** starts and show the image on the screen (during charging).
4. User stops charging the phone, my application hides the image.

How could I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If i remember correctly you can get the "ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED" event with a BroadcastReceiver to do whatever you want. Just Google, there are pretty good tutorials ;)

Comment: `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` and `BroadcastReceiver` is a good way to go, thanks :) However, when user plug the charger and my application is not running/paused, I don't receive that action :/ I want to start my application automatically when user plug the charger / starts charging the phone.

Comment: You have to declare the BroadcastReceiver in your manifest. Then the method is called even if your app is not running in the background. From there you can start the rest that you need.